# What does $x\in (0,1)$ mean?

Tags: functions

What does $ x \in (0,1)$ mean? Does it mean $x = 0$ or $x=1$ or does it mean $0<x<1$?
I know $x \in \{0,1\}$ but in this case it has parentheses instead of curly brackets which confuses me. Sorry for the very easy question I am just a bit confused what the different kinds of brackets mean.

Comment: Considering $(0,1)$ as an ordered pair, $(0,1)=\{\{0\},\{0,1\}\}$, hence $x=\{0\}$ or $x=\{0,1\}$. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It (typically) means $0<x<1$.

The parentheses $(a,b)$ refer to the "open interval", whereas the hard brackets $[a,b]$ refer to the closed interval. Sometimes the open interval is also denoted by reversed hard brackets $]a,b[$. See e.g., from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology):

> An open interval does not include its endpoints, and is indicated with parentheses. For example, $(0,1)$ means greater than $0$ and less than $1$. This means $(0,1) = \{x \mid 0 < x < 1\}$. A closed interval is an interval which includes all its limit points, and is denoted with square brackets. For example, $[0,1]$ means greater than or equal to $0$ and less than or equal to $1$. A half-open interval includes only one of its endpoints, and is denoted by mixing the notations for open and closed intervals. $(0,1]$ means greater than $0$ and less than or equal to $1$, while $[0,1)$ means greater than or equal to $0$ and less than $1$.

Comment: Note that $]a, b[$ is a common notation for the open interval $(a, b)$ too.

Comment: Yes, that's actually the notation I grew up with myself (in Europe).

Comment: Me too :) ${}{}$

Comment: The two endpoints' brackets can be chosen independently, so we can also denote sets that include only one endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the parenthesis notation is commonly used for very different things, but if used as the second argument of the $\in$ relation, it almost certainly denotes the open interval between $0$ and $1$, that is,
$$(0,1) = \{x\in\mathbb R: 0<x<1\}.$$
Therefore $x\in(0,1)$ means $0<x<1$.